# Skip over lines in a csv if exception is thrown Java Stream

Tags: java, csv, java-stream

I'm using Java 8 Stream class to read a .csv file that is about 500Mb, almost all of the data is formatted the same, except for 2 instances i found. There's 52 lines for each object that i store in an ArrayList then add them to a HashMap so I can access them based on keys. I use the HashMap to create an excel file for each object using a different class, then clear the List as soon as the file is created and move on to another object. The problem is when it comes up to the line that has fewer numbers in it, the excel creation class tries to get numbers from indices that are non-existent which throws a NullPointerException. Is there a way to skip these lines if a NullPointerException is thrown? I know that if this problem arises i have to skip 52 lines.

```
try
    {
        final String regex = "\\d*\\.?\\d+";
        Stream<String> lines = Files.lines( file, StandardCharsets.UTF_8 );
        for( String line : (Iterable<String>) lines.skip(currentLine)::iterator ){
            final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
            final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line.substring(0));
            while (matcher.find()) {
                testPop.add(Double.parseDouble(matcher.group(0)));
            }               
            currentLine++;
            if(currentLine%52==0) {
                for(int i =0;i<52;i++) {
                    int date=4+29*i;
                    int a=13+29*i;
                    int b=6+29*i;
                    int c=15+29*i;
                    int d=16+29*i;
                    int e=8+29*i;
                    int f=17+29*i;
                    int g=14+29*i;
                    int h=7+29*i;
                    WeeklyCalculations.put(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf((int)((testPop.get(date))/1))),new Calculations(testPop.get(a),3,1,testPop.get(b),testPop.get(c),testPop.get(d),testPop.get(e),testPop.get(f),testPop.get(g),testPop.get(h),testPop.get(date),WeeklyCalculations));
                }
                findZeroStockOuts();
                ExcelCreator x = new ExcelCreator(WeeklyCalculations,String.valueOf(((int)(testPop.get(1)/1))),String.valueOf(((int)(testPop.get(2)/1))), noStockouts, stockOuts);
                x.createExcel();
                testPop.clear();
                WeeklyCalculations.clear();
                counter++;
                System.out.println(counter + "/" + "67101 - "+TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(System.nanoTime(), TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS));

            }
        }

    } catch (IOException ioe){
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(NullPointerException x) {
        readToExcel(currentLine+52);
    }
```

I was able to skip them inside the loop, but that decreases the speed by huge amounts, considering its around 3.5 million lines and it has to skip through all of them after each iteration. Is there an efficient way to do this?

Comment: Your code is so convoluted, and the question unclear, that it's hard to understand what you're looking for. It'd be better if you posted a sample line from the csv file, even if not all of it, and walked through the code. Like `a,b,c...` is my line, it gets converted to instance of a `List` containing these fields, and then I create a `Map` with the key from index 0, which is `a`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why is slow is because you repeatedly read file from the begin. Fill your code in below block:

```
final String regex = "\\d*\\.?\\d+";
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(file, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
    final Iterator<String> iter = lines.iterator();

    for (int currentLine = 1; iter.hasNext(); currentLine++) {
        String line = iter.next();
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line); // No reason do: line.substring(0)
        while (matcher.find()) {
            // testPop.add(Double.parseDouble(matcher.group(0)));
        }

        try {
            if (currentLine % 52 == 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
                    // TODO
                }
            }

            // TODO:
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
            while (currentLine % 52 != 0 && iter.hasNext()) {
                iter.next();
                currentLine++;
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException x) {
            // readToExcel(currentLine + 52);
            while (currentLine % 52 != 0 && iter.hasNext()) {
                iter.next();
                currentLine++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how to simplify the codes by [Fork of StreamEx](https://github.com/landawn/streamex):

```
final String regex = "\\d*\\.?\\d+";
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

try (StreamEx<String> stream = StreamEx.ofLines(file, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
    stream.splitToList(52).filter(l -> l.size() == 52).forEach(lines -> {
        lines.stream().forEach(line -> {
            final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line); // No reason do: line.substring(0)
            while (matcher.find()) {
                // testPop.add(Double.parseDouble(matcher.group(0)));
            }
        });

        try {
            // TODO:
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NullPointerException x) {
            // readToExcel(currentLine + 52);
        }
    });
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```